# The VM could not be imported; the end of the file was reached prematurely

Tags: xenserver

I am trying to transfer VMs from XenServer 5.6 to XenServer 6.0.

I exported the VMs from XenServer 5.6 to .xva files on my desktop.  Then when I tried to import one into XenServer 6.0, this error message appeared:

> The VM could not be imported; the end of the file was reached prematurely.

What does that mean?
When I tried to export it to another XenServer 5.6 the same message appeared.

Answer (score 1):

If your desktop is a windows and you xva file is larger than 4GB, it will be truncated to a 4GB file. Try to copy it on the fly from one server to another via scp

```
me@oldxen:~$ scp file.xva me@newxen:/path/to/copy/the/file/on/.
```

Comment: Only if he's using FAT32. Though file corruption does seem a likely cause.

Comment: indeed, 16GB for NTFS Filesystem

Comment: More like 16TB!